# CSS don't work in (( Create )) Controller - laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new in laravel.
everything is ok when return view is in  index function like below in Http/Controllers :

```
public function index() 
 { 
    return view('admin.post.post'); }
```

but  when move the return view to create function like below :

```
public function create()
 {
   return view('admin.post.post'); }
```

page load without css and js and in inspect element no css is loaded in chrome's inspect element.
i use laravel blade lauyout. 
Laravel : 5.6.21
PHP :  7.1.16

Comment: How do you load CSS  file??

Comment: check "Network" tab in browser's Developer tools. I believe the root cause is about you miss `<base>` in your HTML + use relative pathes to CSS/JS files(that's fine). So once page has URL different than "yourdomain-here/" CSS and JS are fetching by wrong URLs.

Comment: all the CSS and JS file are on public folder 
@Alihosseinshahabi

Comment: please show your  `blade` file.

Comment: What is the view look like?

Comment: sry. I do'nt get what exactly you mean but i push the project to this address:
[link](https://gitlab.com/Dr.Nefario/blog.test) 

@skyboyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your codes.note these points:

- Do not use Space as much as possible in the folder name. for example, convert `Raw files` to `Raw_files`
- Place `image` files, `CSS` files and `javascript` files in the `Public` folder, so you can access them
- Use the `asset` function to load CSS,javascript and images files.
  for example :

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href={{asset('Raw_files/admin/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css')}}">`